# universal cover of the sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

what is the map $S^n \longrightarrow S^n$ that defines $S^n$ as the universal cover of $S^n$ ?

Answer (score 16):

Since $S^n$ is simply connected for $n \geq 2$ and the identity is a covering map, the identity will do. But note that the universal cover is *not* uniquely determined (it is only unique up to an isomorphism of covering spaces), so there is no *the* map. In fact, any self-homeomorphism $\phi$ of $S^{n}$ will be a universal cover $\phi: S^{n} \to S^n$.

The case $n = 1$ is different, since $S^1$ is not simply connected. Its universal cover is e.g. given the exponential map $t \mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$ from $\mathbb{R} \to S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \,:\,|z| = 1\}$. For every $k \in \mathbb{Z} \smallsetminus \{0\}$ the map $z \mapsto z^{k}$ will determine a self-covering $S^1 \to S^1$ but none of these can be a universal covering.